# How to host external angular component in an angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular

In earlier versions of angular, I was able to dynamically compile angular code to inject it into a page.  I believe this went away in angular 14.

What I want to do is allow users to build angular components and compile them into a library and upload it to my system. I will store the code in a database. Then on certain pages, I want to load the component from the database and inject it into the page dynamically.

I have not been able to find an example of how to do this.  I am open to alternative ideas. My main goal is to be able to let my users write extensions to my product using angular components.

Here are the steps I think are involved to inject the compiled component:

1. inject script block into the page referencing a URL that returns the angular library to inject.
2. Once the script is loaded, import the component into the application.
3. Create the component.
4. Attach the component to the DOM.
5. Initialize the component.

Hopefully somebody has done something similar and they can point me in the right direction. Any help is appreciated.